# $_SESSION Variable not being replaced?

Tags: php, session

The second bit of code I need to replace my current SESSION variable but instead it's adding a new one.  For example: $_SESSION['client'] = 254921, and then the if statement in the second bit should replace it with the new one entered from my $_POST variable.  But instead, if I change it to 254922, $_SESSION['client'] is now equal to 254921 and 254922.  How can I make 254922 replace 254921?  Thanks.

```
<?php
if(empty($_SESSION['client']) || empty($_SESSION['hash'])) {
        $secrets = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `secrets`"));
        $_SESSION['client'] = rand(100000, 999999);
        $_SESSION['rand'] = rand(0, 10000)/100;
        $_SESSION['hash'] = hash('sha512', $_SESSION['rand'] . $_SESSION['client'] . $secrets['secret'] );


 }
 ?>

<?php
    if(!empty($_POST['client']) 
&& strlen($_POST['client']) == 6 
&& is_numeric($_POST['client'])) {

    $_SESSION['client'] = $_POST['client'];


}
?>
```

Comment: Your code as presented looks good to me.  Try enabling error reporting including E_ALL as this will pick up most variable name typos.  I suspect that you are missing a session_start() somewhere.  If this does not work, try debugging by echoing the values of $_SESSION and $_POST before and after the variable is set.  BTW !empty($_POST['client']) is unnecessary as the lack of emptiness is covered by your strlen logic.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this :

```
$_SESSION['client'] = $_POST['client'];
```

By this:

```
unset($_SESSION['client']); // this will unset the variable $_SESSION['client']
$_SESSION['client'] = $_POST['client'];
```

I hope this will be of some help.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.  When I say tried I mean prior to your post.